# Intalled Ubuntu alongside Win 8.1 and it goes only to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS without turning off Fast Startup in Windows 8.1 as I was unaware that this needed to be done. I've installed Ubuntu many times before, but this was my first time with windows 8.1, and unfortunately I didn't look up anything before I did it. I resized the partition and installed Ubuntu successfully and upon reboot, it went directly to Ubuntu without grub showing up. Is there anything I can do as the windows partition is my primary one and there is software that I need access to on it.

Comment: @Cerran actually if you don't correctly shutdown windows, Ubuntu can't mount the NTFS partition to allow GRUB to add it.

Answer (score 1):

The answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) may help you. Using `boot-repair` from a live CD/USB drive is probably the best option because it's a utility designed to fix these kinds of problems. Otherwise, you can try reinstalling grub yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Press `shift` to open GRUB menu,and then go to windows 8.